# R : qvalue package - smoother or bootstrap method for pi0 estimation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I've a bunch of 500 p-values and I want to estimate the pi0 (proportion of true H0). When using the qvalue R package, two method can be used (smoother or bootstrap). Both giving very different results :

- smoother : pi0 = 0.9913
- bootstrap : pi0 = 0.234

Here are the histogram for smoother (top) and bootstrap (bottom). Do I miss something ? Which one to use ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]